# How to stop ajax communication with Primefaces poll component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.2 and I am using polling. I am able to call stop on the poll but something is running in Firebug after that polling.  It stops only if the page gets refreshed.  How to stop that call which is running behind.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: using java script poll.stop();

Comment: I dont think poll.stop() actually stops the call (it only ignores any incoming response). That s why you see it in firebug

Comment: how i have to stop this, even i have used                               RequestContext reqCtx = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
                            reqCtx.execute("poll.stop()");

Comment: You can t make Firefox stop the call. It will still wait for an answer whatever you do. That shouldn't bother you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

poll.stop() only ignores the incoming response and does not cancell the call.

You cannot stop an Ajax call once it s made (unless you refresh the page)

Firebug shows that Ajax call which is still running, but your code will ignore it.

Comment: but session not gets expired because of that call it keeps on adds the session.

Comment: I don't understand so the server never answers back?

Comment: @wild The main reason that someone would use a poll is to make sure that the session never expires.  Perhaps you can keep a timestamp in your session to track how old it is, and manually expire it in your server event when necessary.

Comment: status dialog also not gets stopped. <p:ajaxStatus style="position: fixed;top: 50%;left: 50%;" id="menuAjaxStatusDialogBox" oncomplete="menuStatusDialog.hide();"
                          onstart="menuStatusDialog.show();" onsuccess="menuStatusDialog.hide();"/>  i am using this status dialog.it keeps on running even after the poll call gets stopped..